# How to touch (create a blank file) in Stata?

Tags: loops, for-loop, stata

I'm aware of the package `touch`, which does exactly this. However after installing and using the package, Stata 12 SE (Mac 10.9.5) says:

> The touch command has been deprecated.

Is there an alternative? I need this to initialize a blank result file, so that I can append my regression result in a loop without caring whether I'm in the first iteration or not.

Comment: I managed to install `touch` from SSC without any problems. I'm on Stata 12. If it doesn't work for you, try `help shell` and create the file using a direct call to your operating system.

Comment: @Roberto have you also tried to use it? I could install it fine, but running the command has no effect. If it works for you I will try again.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I downloaded **touch** to Stata 13 and got the same error as Heisenberg.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I'm using Stata 12 SE, Mac OS 10.9.5

Comment: @Heisenberg: Yes, it worked fine for a .csv file. I'm on Linux Mint Debian.

Comment: Would someone know why the deperecated message appears? @Heisenberg: the simplest answer is to use the code of `touch` (`viewsource touch.ado`) with a new name like touch2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

Use one of the following in your do file to create the blank xls file "newfile.xls":

```
shell echo /dev/null > newfile.xls
```

which will overwrite existing files of the same name. To create a new blank file of that name:

```
shell touch newfile.xls
```

would also work. However if a file of the same name exists, **touch** would only change the modification and access times.

**OLD ANSWER**

The following will save an empty Stata data file "newdata.dta".  Substitute your own name.

```
save newdata, emptyok
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I was trying to initialize a blank `.xls` file in order to append regression result.

Comment: I will append to the xls file using outreg2, a package to output regression result into Excel table

Comment: Exactly how are you going to append xls files in a Stata loop? append operates only on Stata data files. So just create and append those in the loop (you must be doing that anyway). After the loop finishes, use the final file (newdata, in the example), and create the xls file with **export excel**.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about `shell` -- once I have access to the shell it's easy. Could you edit your answer to `shell echo /dev/null > newfile.xls`? This solution will also overwrite old files of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

With Mac, you can just use the native touch: `!touch filename.xls`,
or
`!> empty_results.txt`, if you want to over-write an existing file or create it if it does not exist.